# JSON is printing instead of redirecting

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Here's a AJAX Login that I did.

```
$(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(){

      var uname = $('#username').val();
      var password = $('#password').val();

      $("#loading").show();
      $("#loading").fadeIn(400);

      $.POST('php/authorization.php', (username: uname, password: password),
          function(asd) {
          if(asd.success){
              location.href = asd.redirect;
          }else{
              $('.error').html(asd.message);
          };
      }, 'json');

      return false;
  });

});
```

and the PHP Snippet

```
if($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($raw))
{
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
  $_SESSION['uid']   = $data['u_id'];
  $_SESSION['uname'] = $data['u_name'];
  $_SESSION['utype'] = $data['u_type'];
  $_SESSION['uactive'] = $data['u_active'];
  mysql_close($link);

  $asd['success']    = true;
  $asd['redirect']   = '../dashboard.php';
}
else 
{
  mysql_close($link);

  $asd['success']   = false;
  $asd['message']   = "Wrong username or password";
}

echo json_encode($asd);
```

The problem is, instead of redirecting or doing any action, the PHP is printing `{"success":true,"redirect":"..\/dashboard.php"}` instead.

Why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've edited the question.. wasn't that what caused the problem?

Comment: Can you update your code snippet to be functional? As it is there are a lot of errors, but they are probably just your typos. `POST` shouldn't be capitalized, you've put `()` instead of `{}`

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "The PHP is printing ... instead"? Do you mean the page is updating to show that? The PHP is supposed to print just what you've shown.

Comment: I think u need to move the return false statement from the ajax callback to the main function

Comment: I mean, instead of redirecting to dashboard.php, it prints the encoded json values. `{"success":true,"redirect":"..\/dashboard.php"}`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$.POST('php/authorization.php', (username: uname, password: password), ...
```

To

```
$.post('php/authorization.php', {username: uname, password: password}, ...
```

I think what is happening to you is that these errors prevent javascript from running, thus the `return false;` is never executed and your form just submits regularly.

Comment: Sorry. That was a silly mistake (I rewrite this code just to ask here, and I missed that one. Edited already). I still wonder why it didn't work out (even though the response object name is correct)

Comment: @YotamOmer The indentation makes it hard to see, but he is returning false from the handler, which should cover that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yeah just looked at it.. :/

Comment: @YotamOmer Changed, but still the same.

Comment: @rolodex I suggest you load the page an open the console. see if any error that prevent javascript from running occurs.

Comment: Thanks @YotamOmer. I have figured out the solution. There seems to be some kind of error in my javascript, but I couldn't find it, so I rewritten the whole function and instead of using `$.post` I used `$.ajax` instead.